iText 7. Wrap text around image with TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED case
Is it possible  to make justified text alignment with floating image correctly?
Now it looks like this:

My code:
val writer = PdfWriter("HelloWorld.pdf")
val pdf = PdfDocument(writer)
val document = Document(pdf)

val txt = (1..40).joinToString { "A Hello World PDF document..." }

val img = Image(ImageDataFactory.create("img.png"))

val scaledSize = img.scaledSize(document, 5f)

img
    .scaleAbsolute(scaledSize.first, scaledSize.second)
    .setMarginRight(16f)
    .setProperty(Property.FLOAT, FloatPropertyValue.LEFT)
    
val paragraph = Paragraph()
    .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED)
    .add(img)
    .add(txt)
    
document.add(paragraph)

document.close()
writer.close()

But if I exclude .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED) it looks normal:

